# returning string properly from method

Tags: c#

i have this method and i wanted to return a string that i will use in another method but not when i place the return statement in the for loop the method is asking for return still. how can i properly structure this so i can return the string i want.

```
public string ReadDocument(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                theImage = codecs.Load(Enhance(fileName), 0, CodecsLoadByteOrder.BgrOrGray, 1, -1); 
                for (int num = 1; num <= theImage.PageCount; num++)
                {
                    BarcodeData dataArray = engine.Reader.ReadBarcode(theImage, LogicalRectangle.Empty, 0, null);
 qrCode = dataArray.Value;

                    if (theImage.Page < theImage.PageCount)
                        theImage.Page++;       
                    return dataArray.Value;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you know when you've found the right string?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something your `for` loop is going to `return` after one iteration.

Comment: Why are you returning before the loop has gone through all of the pages?

Comment: @PatLillis because each page has a guid that is not the same for all pages. I should probably keep a list and then return that list

Comment: If I'm understanding your intended functionality, then on each loop iteration, you should append `dataArray.Value` to a string declared _outside_ the loop, and then then return that string _after_ the loop is finished (Probably after the catch block too).

Comment: @PatLillis so something like what Sachin below as suggested as an answer and i should probably have that string to be an array.

Comment: Sure, since you have `theImage.PageCount` for the size of the array. As an aside: why not have the for loop use `theImage.Page` for the counter: `for (theImage.Page = 1 ; theImage.Page < theImage.PageCount; theImage.Page++)`

Answer (score 4):

In order for this code to compile you should think of the value you need to return in case of an exception and in case your `for` loop never ran (yeah this could happen if `theImage.PageCount` returns a value which is strictly inferior to 1 at runtime). For example you could return `null`:

```
public string ReadDocument(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        theImage = codecs.Load(Enhance(fileName), 0, CodecsLoadByteOrder.BgrOrGray, 1, -1); 
        for (int num = 1; num <= theImage.PageCount; num++)
        {
            BarcodeData dataArray = engine.Reader.ReadBarcode(theImage, LogicalRectangle.Empty, 0, null);
            qrCode = dataArray.Value;

            if (theImage.Page < theImage.PageCount)
            {
                theImage.Page++;
            }

            return dataArray.Value;
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: Is it intended to have a for loop that can only loop once? -1

Comment: @C.Lang, `theImage.PageCount` is a value that is evaluated and only known at runtime. No matter what assumptions you make at compile time, those assumptions could be proven wrong pretty fast at compile time. That's why the compiler is emitting an error with this code. It simply refuses it to compile because it wouldn't know what to return in case `theImage.PageCount < 1`.

Comment: But why use a for loop. Maybe I'm confused but there's no possible way that loop will ever run more than once no?

Comment: What makes you think that this loop cannot run more than once? It will all depend on some runtime variable values. You've got a `theImage.PageCount` variable involved here. You cannot know at compile time what will be the value of this variable. It can be 0, it can be 5, or 5000.

Comment: Because of the `return dataArray.Value;` inside of it that isn't protected by some condition.

Comment: The body of the `for` loop might never execute if `theImage.PageCount < 1`, right? So the OP's code will never return a value, right? This impossible right? That's why you get a compile time error telling you `hey, you wrote a method that should return a string value and in your implementation there's a case which you didn't specify, so go ahead and check your code`.

Comment: @C.Lang i take care of checking for all this in an upper level place making sure that the file exists and isn't corrupt and and the code above i removed the checking conditions to minimize the code on the screen and just focused on my concern. Thank you both!

Comment: I gave you your 1 back, but I still don't see the point of the `for`. But I shouldn't have downvoted it though because that's what the op is doing. My point was if I have a for loop that returns on the first iteration, it's only a for loop in signature. It seems needlessly confusing like `for(int i=0; i<someHugeNum; ++i) return i;` Why do that?

Comment: @C.Lang i will be changing that so that i will return an array because a file (theImage) could contain more than 1 page and each page has a different id (which i am trying to return) so i will create an array and save each id from each page of the file and then return the array

Comment: @loop852 Use an Enumerator instead of an array.

Answer (score 3):

You might get the error like *not all code paths return value* because you are not returning anything from `catch` statement.

You can just save the value of `dataArray.Value` in string and then return this value after outside the catch statement (at the last).

```
public string ReadDocument(string fileName)
{
    string value = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        theImage = codecs.Load(Enhance(fileName), 0, CodecsLoadByteOrder.BgrOrGray, 1, -1);
        for (int num = 1; num <= theImage.PageCount; num++)
        {
            BarcodeData dataArray = engine.Reader.ReadBarcode(theImage, LogicalRectangle.Empty, 0, null);
            qrCode = dataArray.Value;

            if (theImage.Page < theImage.PageCount)
                theImage.Page++;
            value = dataArray.Value;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    return value;
}
```

**Update:** If you want to return the List then Just change the return type to `List<string>` and then add item to string and return it like this

```
List<string> myValues=new List<string>();
for (int num = 1; num <= theImage.PageCount; num++)
        {
            BarcodeData dataArray = engine.Reader.ReadBarcode(theImage, LogicalRectangle.Empty, 0, null);
            qrCode = dataArray.Value;
        if (theImage.Page < theImage.PageCount)
            theImage.Page++;
        myValues.Add(dataArray.Value);
    }
```

and then return `myValues`

Comment: How can i change this so that the string value is an array so i can add to it all the values and then return a list

Comment: for that use List<string>, Add all values to it and then return the List.

Comment: @loop852 I have updated code for returning the List from function

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to return a correct string here, since the method failed its postcondition.  You asked it to read a document, and it didn't.  You have three potential options that make sense:

1. Return null.  You'll then have to handle a null in the caller.
2. Don't catch the exception, if you aren't able to handle it -- let the caller handle it.
3. Catch the exception, but rethrow it, wrapped in some other type to reflect your method's failed postcondition.

If you don't rethrow from your catch, the compiler expects you to return something -- hence, null.

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading individual barcodes here, I'd suggest using an `IEnumerable<string>` and the `yield return` operator over actually concatenating the string right away.

Here's what I mean; I have a few sample "pages" here, which will of course be actual data in your program, but it gives us something to work with:

```
    // Example "pages", which would be individual barcodes read using OP's BarcodeReader, but we need some sample data to demonstrate the purpose.
    private string[] _pages = new string[] { "Mung", "Foo", "Bar", "Cookie" };
```

Then you'd write your `ReadDocument` method somewhere along the lines of this:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> ReadDocument()
    {
        // Iterate over the pages, and use yield return to add every individual page to the IEnumerable.
        // Using the current Page and the PageLength in your for loop removes the need of having to manually check
        // whether we've reached the end of the pages further down the loop.
        for (int i = 0; i < _pages.Length; i++)
        {
            // BarcodeData dataArray = engine.Reader.ReadBarcode(theImage, LogicalRectangle.Empty, 0, null);
            // qrCode = dataArray.Value;

            yield return _pages[i]; // dataArray.Value in your own code.
        }
    }
```

That'll give you all the pages you've just read in a nice `IEnumerable` which you can `foreach` over later to get the individual pages, or you could get the string of all pages combined by doing something along the lines of

`ReadDocument().Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, s) => current + s);`

The benefit this approach has over directly merging all of your read pages into a string is that you still have access to all the data in its raw form, and you can operate on it freely, without the need to maybe `Split()` it afterwards.

The code isn't exactly your own code anymore, but it should provide you with a clear idea of how I'd suggest you approach this specific problem; you should be able to adapt it and use it in your own code without too many issues.